# Error on .ics file import

Tags: solspace-calendar

When I try to import a google generated .ics file I get the following error and no events are imported:

An Error Was Encountered
You are not authorized to access this page

The url I am using is:
http://www.google.com/calendar/ical/sp9rt0e3ikdfelf06mckpfjmhs@group.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics

Strangely, if I use this one, I still get the error, but events are imported:
https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/canadian__en@holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics

any ideas?

Comment: Did you assign another custom field group to the "Calendar: Calendars" or "Calendar: Events" _channels_, or the other way around: did you assign the "Calendar: Calendars" and "Calendar: Events" _custom field groups_ to other channels than those created by Calendar upon installation? **You \*must\* use the channels and custom field groups provided by Calendar upon installation.**

Comment: I have the correct groups assigned. I have added some extra fields, but that should not be a problem correct?like I said I can get events to import events with SOME .ics files, but I always get the error.

Comment: What version of Calendar are you using? I tested that first (problematic) ICS URL, and had no issue importing it. It is indeed a publicly accessible URL, is that correct? Are you trying to import as a Super Admin? If as another member, does this member have the right permissions to create a calendar?

Comment: Calendar is: v1.8.9, EE is v2.7.2 The URL is public and I am Super Admin. One of the custom fields I have added to events is a P&T Field Pack Switch type.

Comment: I just deleted the three custom fields that I had added and tried the import again, and got a different error. A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1054 Unknown column 'field_id_' in 'field list' [then it printed the query]

Comment: We'll probably have to dive in to have a closer look. You'll have to file a ticket with us at support.solspace.com. Please provide CP and FTP credentials, and please mention this thread and the entry you're working on. Thanks!

Comment: Did this get resolved? I have the same issue.

Comment: after i updated to the latest version, i found that I needed to delete all previous calendars and then and only then would it work.